# Install "libssl1.0-dev" package on Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspbian, debian

I'd like to install telegram ([Github Link](https://github.com/vysheng/tg)) on my RPi 3 B+ (running the newest stretch) but I get an error when compiling. 
I asked on GitHub ([Link](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/issues/1535#issuecomment-397902350)) and was told I need to install the "libssl1.0-dev" package.

That's were I'm stuck. I don't know how to install this libssl1.0-dev package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use apt: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Right, I saw that issue thread on GitHub...

I checked the Debian `apt` repos, the package `libssl1.0-dev` is definitely there. Since Raspbian is based on Debian, the package should exist on Raspbian too. Therefore, to install it:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev`